# Why does Audacity consider 320kpbs "insane" quality for mp3s?

Tags: audacity

The title says it all.  I know they're just having a bit of fun with the name, but it seems to imply that such quality is basically not needed.  Why is that?

Comment: I challenge you to try a blind A-B test and see if you can hear the difference in quality.

Comment: To the people who are down voting. Please leave a comment I don’t know why this is a low quality question. It sure would be nice to know.

Comment: @xerotolerant: thanks. I'm also curious. If I can make the question better I'm happy to.

Comment: mp3 is outdated, you should really be using something like ogg which gives you higher definition in the same bitrate and plays on nearly anything.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. It's been a while since I've even thought of storing songs to be honest, but it did come up as I'm now starting to record things.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Also while lossy formats are fine for listening, if you plan to record your own music, store the files in a lossless format (wav, flac) *at least* all the way from recording to the final mixdown.

Comment: For sure. I'm recording in whatever audacity natively saved it as. I'm not sure what it is but the files are huge, like 50MB per minute.

Comment: You can select, from a few options, what format Audacity saves its projects in. Edit->Preferences:Quality. With the options 44100Hz and 16-bit, stereo recordings use up ~10MB per minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there's hardly any audible improvement [past 196 kbps](https://superuser.com/questions/555118/tool-to-help-compare-mp3-bitrate-quality), so 320 is an unjustifiable ("insane") waste of disk space.  Many listeners have measured this for themselves with an [ABX test](https://www.head-fi.org/threads/when-is-mp3-transparent-an-abx-test-of-compressed-audio-versus-lossless.747533/).

Comment: Quite an old question, but no one has really put down the answer yet. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky the name actually comes not from audacity, but from preset of _lame_, which is mp3 encoder used by audacity.